# How to check matching failures with fscanf in C

Tags: c, error-handling, scanf

I would like to be able to figure out if the file I am reading doesn't contain the wrong type of data without stoping the reading.

For instance : here I want to store some integers from a file, but if there is some chars in my file it will stop the loop. I dont know how I can avoid this and how I can return an error of matching type.

```
int main (void) {
    FILE* input_file = fopen("toto.txt", "r");

    int a [10];

    if (input_file != NULL) {
        int i =0;
        while (fscanf(input_file, "%d", &a[i]) == 1) {
            //do something
        }
        fclose(input_file);
    }
    else {
        printf ("open failed.");
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Write your own parser. Read a file char by char, check all conditions, use strtoll to convert string to numbers,

Comment: `fscanf(input_file, "%d %d", &a[i])` is undefined behavior - you have two format specifiers but only one argument.

Comment: @AndrewHenle edited, my mistake

Comment: Thanks.  I'll echo @KamilCuk's comment here: you really can't use any of the `scanf()` family for reliably parsing possibly-wrong data.  The f in scan**f** itself comes from "formatted" - as in "scan formatted data".  The functions presume input data already matches a very tight format, and they really do fail badly and in potentially unpredictable ways on unexpected data types.

Comment: "but if there is some chars in my file it will stop the loop." --> Clearly state what you want code to do when this happens.  Just ignore the characters?

Comment: What should code do if the integer value read does not fit in an `int`?  Ignore _all_ those digits?  `"123456789012345678901234567890 +123"` does what?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Okay, i'll do it in another way then. Thanks both of you for the answers.

Comment: @chux I would like to log an error like "wrong input type" but continue the reading

Comment: Somebody took already care of it, all I wanted. @chux

Answer (score 2):

If scanf cannot convert the input with the format item, it returns without consuming the character which caused the error. The return value is either the number of successful conversions or `EOF` if end of file (or a read error) was encountered with no successful conversions.

If your format has only one conversion item, there are only three possible return values:

```
EOF  End of input (or read error)
0    Invalid character
1    Succesful conversion
```

In the second case, if you want to continue parsing, you need to consume the erroneous character, which you could do with `scanf("%*c");`.

`scanf` is not a very precise tool for parsing input. For example, it will not distinguish between

```
223abc
```

and

```
223 abc
```

Both will be treated as a succesful `%d` conversion followed by no success; there is no way of telling whether there was whitespace.

If you're OK with the various limitations, go ahead and use it, but if you want to do real input validation, you will eventually hit a brick wall for which the only solution is "use a different tool".

Comment: Im not sure to understand how consuming the erroneous character with `scanf("*c");`. Can you explain a little more ?

Comment: @djadjik: it's`"%*c"` (thanks to Jonathan Leffler for the edit). That matches exactly one character (`%c`) and discards it (`*`). See [`man scanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process errors, you can look at a structure like this:

```
    int i = 0;
    int rc;
    while ((rc = fscanf(input_file, "%d", &a[i])) != EOF)
    {
        if (rc == 1)
        {
            …success…
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            …deal with error…
        }
    }
```

Normally, I encourage the use of `fscanf(…) != 1` in the loop condition; it stops the loop if there's a problem.  However, if you want to handle the error and continue the loop, this condition is more suitable.  How you deal with the error is up to you.  You might skip and ignore (or report) the characters up to the next white space, or up to the next newline.  Or you might look for a command or other information in the text that didn't match the number.

One option you should consider is using [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX 
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read a line of data, and then use [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) to parse the line.  There are at least two principle advantages to this approach:

- You can report the whole line that's giving the error, not just the wreckage that's left when `fscanf()` has partially consumed it.
- You can parse the same data multiple different ways, which can be advantageous.

Comment: I also thought of a structure like yours but we got into an infinite loop when a read error occurs...
I'll try your second option.